# scikit-learn Spectral Clustering results in disconnected clusters

Tags: python, graph, scikit-learn, scipy, cluster-analysis

I am trying to perform spectral clustering on a large affinity matrix. I am representing my matrix as a scipy sparse matrix, and recursively calling spectral clustering to bisect the matrix. I am calling the spectral_clustering function using the following parameters:

```
clustering = spectral_clustering(W, n_clusters=2, eigen_solver='amg', assign_labels="cluster_qr", random_state=0)
```

However, I notice that my a few of my resulting clusters are disconnected. During the clustering run, no errors/warning were thrown, though occasionally there is a "graph is disconnected" warning. But I believe that should not be an issue.

I have checked that they have 0 weights assigned betweem them in the initial affinity matrix, so it seems like it is a result of spectral_clustering itself. Any idea as to why this might be happening?

Thank you so much for the help and let me know if you need any clarifications!

Edit: I realize that the eigensolver uses lobpcg which usually computes an approximate eigenvector. I am thinking that perhaps since it is an approximation, the eigenvector is not exact and this might lead to disconnected results? Is this a possible explanation? and if so, how does one get around this problem?

Comment: You may get better results if you adjust the title and tag to reflect that you mean "scikit-learn" `spectral_clustering`, since SciPy doesn't contain spectral clustering. Note that the documentation of `sklearn.cluster.spectral_clustering`states "The graph should contain only one connected component, elsewhere the results make little sense." Maybe your problem is a manifestation of "[making] little sense" and you should try a different algorithm.